# LINQ: Get all items of a list within a list

Tags: c#, linq

I've an ObservableCollection which includes another ObservableCollection.

```
ObservableCollection<MyModel> models = new ObservableCollection<MyModel>();
```

My models looks like that:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<MyModel2> list2 { get; set; }
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
}

public class MyModel2
{
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
    public string Property3 { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to find all MyModel2 items in models which "Property2" == "test1" and "Property3" == "test2"

I know how to search in just one list2 to find the right items, but i want to search in all "list2" in the models-collection.

```
var result = from mod 
             in list2
             where mod.Property2 == "test1" && mod.Property3 == "test2"
             select mod;
```

Any help would be grateful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want something like:

```
var query = from model in models
            from model2 in model.list2
            where model2.Property2 == "test1" && model2.Property == "test2"
            select model2;
```

Or in non-query expression form:

```
var query = models.SelectMany(model => model.list2)
                  .Where(model2 => model2.Property2 == "test1"
                                   && model2.Property == "test2");
```

Comment: `.Select` => `.SelectMany`?

Answer (score 1):

```
var result =
    models.SelectMany(item => item.list2.Where(model => model.Property2 == "test1" && model.Property3 == "test2"));
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Enumerable.SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx) and [`Enumerable.Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx) on the "inner" list:

```
models.SelectMany(m => 
    m.list2.Where(m2 => m2.Property2 == "test1" && m2.Property3 == "test2"));
```